# Keyboard shortcut to cleanup code in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

What is the keyboard shortcut to cleanup code in IntelliJ WebStorm?

I keep getting the "Unterminated statement" warning and have to select "cleanup code" option every time to fix it. Is there a keyboard shortcut for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you double-click shift it will open a search-all window, where you can type literally anything, and it will search IDE options, files, symbols, etc.

Do that and type in 'cleanup code', see what happens. On the right side, there should be a keyboard shortcut. If there isn't any, you can assign it with settings windows.